# Japanese message is truncated in chat window for iOS user

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios

I'm using ServiceSDK/Chat version '214.0.3' in an iOS App.

The issue that we have is that any Japanese message is displayed truncated on iOS 13.x devices: the last line is not displayed in the chat UI for the mobile user:

- if the mobile user types a Japanese message and taps send then this message is displayed truncated in the chat window. The SF agent gets the full message though.
- similar, a Japanese message sent by the SF agent is displayed truncated in the chat window. So, the mobile user doesn't get the full message.

Please, check attached screenshots.

Could you point to some solution/workaround for this issue?

Any solution that would work with ServiceSDK 214.0.3 and iOS 13.x?

Thanks.

[image]
[image]
[image]